# Question About No Output From strace

Tags: apache-2.2, strace

I am using strace to see what certain processes are doing. I have an Apache process that seems to be running forever, taking up 97.8% of a core and almost 2GB of RAM.

Now when I run strace on this process there is no output at all. Does this mean that the process is dead and sitting in there taking up resources? Can I kill the process without worrying about doing something bad?

I am running strace in the following way:

strace -p6873

Thanks

Josh Pennington

Comment: it can be another inner process running and the main one is waiting = no output. check it and try a different PID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process seems to be stuck in a single long-running syscall. Since `strace` doesn't show the syscall that was running, when it attached the process, you get no output.
You could maybe get more info using a debugger like `gdb` and running a stack trace (gdb command: `bt`).

Comment: It also might be doing internal processing; strace only sees syscalls, but not all calls are syscalls... a tight infinite loop (bug) would also just hang as above.

Comment: You're probably right, hence the high cpu usage.

Comment: "Since strace doesn't show the syscall that was running" -- I disagree; when I strace a process blocked in a syscall I see a partial line like `write(1, "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n"..., 4096` or `futex(0x7f2b3c14fe54, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 59, NULL`

Comment: No, what you do see is `restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted xyz ...>)` where xyz is the syscall. See pjz's comment for the more correct explanation.